# Adding only the values of a list to another list in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, append

I am trying to add and extend the items of a list in a loop as follows:

```
y_predicts=[]
y_trues=[]

for train,test in cv.split(X,y):
    predict = classifier.fit(X.iloc[train],y.iloc[train]).predict(X.iloc[test])
    tmp_l=predict.tolist()
    y_predicts.append(tmp_l)
    y_trues.append(np.array(y.iloc[test]))
```

The result of the above code is something like this:

```
print(y_predicts):
    [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

But, my desired output should something like this:

```
print(y_predicts):
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: You will want `extend`, not `append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python [two sequence types can be concatenated](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) with a `+` operator. This can also happen in-place with the `+=` operator

Instead of

```
y_predicts.append(tmp_l)
```

you should use

```
y_predicts += tmp_l
```

in your loop.

Another way of adding all items from one list to another is the [`extend` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of the list . In contrast to the `append` method which adds the given item as a whole to the list, `extend` appends all its items to the list:

```
y_predicts.extend(tmp_l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extend()` instead of `append()` it will add the elements from the passed in list rather than the list itself.

```
b = []
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = [6,7, 8]

b.extend(a)
b.extend(c)
print(b)

# > [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way to combine two lists items together as a single list item is to use "extend" keyword instead of append.

```
 y_predicts=[]
  y_trues=[]

  for train,test in cv.split(X,y):
      predict = classifier.fit(X.iloc[train],y.iloc[train]).predict(X.iloc[test])
      tmp_l=predict.tolist()
      y_predicts.extend(tmp_l)
      y_trues.append(np.array(y.iloc[test]))
```